# How do I call a method function from a class with more than one object/field

Tags: c++, function, class

I create the following class as an exmaple

```
class Date{

public:
   setDate( Date &obj );

private:
   int day, month, year;

};
```

Then in the `main()` I'd like to use the function `setDate()` but how do I fill the `date & obj` in this case?

```
void main(){

    Date * today;
    today->setDate( ??? );
}
```

Comment: Pass it another `Date` object. Also use `today->setDate()`, and the argument should probably be changed to `Date const &`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to set the date. The interface suggests you can only set the date to another date object, meaning there is no specify an arbitrary date.

Comment: You've created a way to set a `Date` from another `Date` but that makes it impossible to set the first `Date`. You probably need a constructor or functions to set the `Date` from its components something like `Date(int day, int month, int year)`.

Comment: @cdhowie  `today.setDate()` is pretty much `today->setDate()`

Comment: @twain249 so you are saying I can't use `Date` same way I use `int` or `char`?

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb No. It's not "pretty much" something totally different.

Comment: @cdhowie when I press `.` my compiler automatically switches it to `->`, so I wouldn't know of it.
anyway I will edit the post

Comment: Why do you use `new` without `delete`? Why do you use `new` at all?

Comment: @tobi303 as far as I know I need to use `new` or at least so I was taught, and this is just an example, not the actual code

Comment: You were taught poorly.  C++ is not Java or C#.  You don't need to use `new` to create an instance of a class.

Comment: to say it clear: Thats just plain wrong. In c++ you create an object via `Date today;`. I suggest you to forget whatever you were taught and [read a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First, don't use naked `new`, and don't use new al all if it is not necessary. Because it can lead to memory leak problems.

2) Don't use a setter just use a constructor.

3) Use `const Date &` in an overloaded `Date` constructor

4) Initialize `Date` with initilizer list. Use the overloaded constructor `Date` to build a `Date` using a const reference to other `Date`

5) In C++ return type of main must be `int`

```
class Date{

  public:
    Date( int dd, int mm, int yyyy);
    Date( const Date &obj );

  private:
    int day, month, year;

};

int main(){

    Date now = {02,06,2017};

    Date today(now);
    return 0;
}
```

---

6) Now if you really need a setter function you can do:

```
class Date{

public:
Date(int day, int month, int year); //A
Date( const Date &obj );  //B

void setDate( const Date &obj );

private:
   int day, month, year;

};

int main(){

    Date now = {02,06,2017};

    Date today(now);

    today.setDate({02,06,2017}); //Setter example using initilizer list + contructor A 
    today.setDate(now); //Setter example
    return 0;
}
```